# Function in component not working after passing in props from another component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props, react-state

I have a working function when I pass an array of data inside the same component.
 This function makes an array of all possible combinations of ingredients, then makes API calls to find all possible drinks, and then filters through to find the ones that only contain the ingredients in the array.
 However, when I try to pass the array of data as props from another component, the function stops working half way through... 
The props are received fine and the function starts but then it stops working on line 64-72. The valid results are not getting pushed to my result array.
The two images show function passed with props and hard coded array:
Any help would be appreciated!!
Component  code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import './style.css'

function MultiSearch({clickState}) {
    //console.log(ingredients)
    console.log(clickState)

const [filtResult, setFiltResult] = useState([])
const ingredients = ['Vodka', 'Orange juice']
//console.log(ingredients)
// use usestate to add salt and other ingredients like that as default. Then add user ingredients onto existing array

function getCombinations(valuesArray) {
    let combi = [];
    let temp = [];
    let slent = Math.pow(2, valuesArray.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slent; i++) {
        temp = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < valuesArray.length; j++) {
            if ((i & Math.pow(2, j))) {
                temp.push(valuesArray[j]);
            }
        }
        if (temp.length > 0) {
            combi.push(temp);
        }
    }
    combi.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
    // console.log(combi.join("\n"));
    console.log(combi.filter(x => x.length > 1))
    combi = combi.filter(x => x.length > 1)
// Fetch data with combinations array    
    let drinkList = []
    let clen = combi.length

    const fetchAll = async (combi) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < clen; i++) {
            let possible = await axios.get(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v2/9973533/filter.php?i=${combi[i].join(',')}`)
            let data = possible.data.drinks
            typeof(data) !== 'string' && drinkList.push(data)
        }
        //flatten array of arrays into one.
        const concatList = drinkList.flat(1)
        let fullList = []
        let conLen = concatList.length
        //lookup each drink into new array with full details
        for (let i = 0; i < conLen; i++) {
            let res = await axios.get(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v2/9973533/lookup.php?i=${concatList[i].idDrink}`)
            let data = res.data.drinks
            fullList.push(data)
        }
        //Flatten array of arrays into single array
        fullList = fullList.flat(1)
        console.log(fullList)
        fullList.length > 0 && ingredients.push('Salt', 'Olive', 'Tea', 'Sugar')
        let result = []
        let valid = true;
*** // Code starts to fail below                             ***
        fullList.map(drink => {
            for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
                console.log(drink[`strIngredient${i}`])
                if (drink[`strIngredient${i}`] !== null && ingredients.indexOf(drink[`strIngredient${i}`]) === -1) {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                } else if (ingredients.indexOf(drink[`strIngredient${i}`]) !== -1){
                    valid = true;
                }
                
            }
           valid === true && result.push(drink)
  ***     // End code fail                                     ***
        })
        console.log(result)
        // Filter result to remove duplicates
        const ids = result.map(x => x.idDrink)
        const filtered = result.filter(({idDrink}, index) => !ids.includes(idDrink, index + 1))
        setFiltResult(filtered)
    }
        fetchAll(combi) 
}
   useEffect(() => {
    getCombinations(ingredients);
   }, [clickState])
   
   
 console.log(filtResult)
   
  return (
    filtResult.length !== 0 ? filtResult.map(drink => {
        console.log(drink)
        const {strDrink, strDrinkThumb} = drink

        return (
            <>
                <h2>{strDrink}</h2>
                <img className="multi-search" src={strDrinkThumb} alt={strDrink} />
            </>
            
        )
    })
    :
    <h2>No search rn</h2> 
  )
}

export default MultiSearch
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are mutating the `ingredients` props in the part where you 'Flatten array of arrays into single array'. When `ingredients` is a local variable, it works fine but when you pass `ingredients` from props, it doesn't work in the expected way. I think copying that prop to a local array might help.

Props mutation

```
fullList.length > 0 && ingredients.push('Salt', 'Olive', 'Tea', 'Sugar')
```

Copying array in function scope

```
function getCombinations(valuesArray) {
  let originalIngredients = [...valuesArray];
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That makes sense to me as props are read only, correct? Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem..

Comment: Did you try replacing all `ingredients` references in the function with a copied value like I shown above as `originalIngredients` ?

Comment: Yeah I replaced all instances of ingredients, but the problem still remains

Comment: I copied and run your code. It works fine with props passing from other component. [See images](https://imgur.com/a/SaOPe7J). I think there's something wrong with data, may be from input.

Comment: Thanks @Zeyar i managed to fix it in the end, ill post answer. Like you said I think it was the inputs being dodgy and potentially my loop being dodgy

Answer (score 0):

the fix:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
               if (drink[`strIngredient${i}`] !== null && !newIngredients.includes(drink[`strIngredient${i}`].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ''))) {
                   valid = false;
                   break;
               } else {
                   valid = true
               }
```